# What the method name of the XmlReader getting the current file path?

Tags: c#, wpf, xmlreader

My application saves the content to the XML file or reads the content from the XML file.
The content is project structure and the XML file can exist everywhere.

For example, the structure of the XML file my application using is as shown below.

```
<Project version="1">
    <Item Include="A.text"/>
    <Item Include="Folder/A.text"/>
</Project>
```

As you can see, the include tag of the Item is a relative path, therefore it needs a root path to open the item. (Project file path)

My application structure to process is as shown below.

```
public class Project, IXmlSerializable
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items {get; set;} = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        // here would read ChildNode (Items)
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        ...
    }
}


public class Item, IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And reading code is as shown below.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(message.ProjectFullPath))
{
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProjectStruct));
    this.Projects.Add(xs.Deserialize(sr) as ProjectStruct);
}
```

As you can see, I created writing, reading logic deriving IXmlSerializable to use Serialize, DeSerialize function.

When the DeSerialize method is called, the ReadXml method of the ProjectStruct would be called. And ReadXml method has not parameter other than XmlReader so I can't pass ProjectFullPath to the ReadXML method.

Therefore I think need to get ProjectFullPath from XmlReader.

Could someone tell me what the method name of the XmlReader getting the current file path?

If you have another way to solve this problem please let me know. I don't obsess my way.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: First observation - Why Item tags in your xml are not withins a parent Items tag. Its not appropriate xml with respect to Xpath querying/processing.

Comment: Secondly - XmlReader will have a property holding the Stream you passed. The Stream when cast to its underlying type will give you the Path to File.

Comment: I don't know what the first comment means. Could you tell me more?
And... the second comment helpful to me. Could you show me an example?

Comment: Your xml could be like: &lt;Project>&lt;Items>&lt;Item Include="First"/>&lt;Item Include="Second"/>&lt;/Items>&lt;/Project>

Comment: @jjw: Is the full path event included in the XML data? How else is an `XmlReader` supposed to get it?

Comment: No not included. my XML data include only a relative path. if the user selects a project to use then the full path be filled into the message.ProjectFullPath. but I don't know a way to pass the message.ProjectFullPath to the ReadXml method of the Project.

Comment: @jjw: That's not possible. Please read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass anything else than the `XmlReader` that the interface defines to the `ReadXml` method.

Depending on how you instantiate the `Item` class, you may be able to inject it with a `string` that defines the path:

```
public class Item(string path)
...
```

If you can't do this, you should include the full path in the XML data and read it from there.

The last resort may be to get it from a static property of `Item` that you set before you begin to process the XML file.

Anyway, you can't modify the signature of the method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.